# mysqli_fetch_assoc returns Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have a connection to a DB where i am using `mysqli_fetch_assoc` to create an assosiative array to return the data to the screen. That part of code looks like this:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Kundregistert ORDER BY ID DESC;";
    //
    //
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    //
    // Avsluta anslutning till db
    return ($row['Namn'], $row['Telefonnummer'], $row['Epost'], $row['Dacktyp'], $row['Lagerstatus'], $row['Datum']);
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

At first i had all the information in the database stored under one column called 'Kund' **(i only used `return $row['Kund']` then since it was only 1 column)**, then it did not supply the foreach error. Now i store the information through 7 variables and want to return all the columns like i am trying to do above.

Here is the code for foreach;

```
foreach($company->getCustomerList() as $key => $obj){
    echo "<h3 id='id'>$key</h3> " . $obj->getcustomername() . ", " . $obj->getcustomertfn() . ", " . $obj->getcustomerepost() . "<br>" . $obj->gettirebrand() . ", " . $obj->getstatus() . ": " . $obj->getdate() . "<br>" . 
    " <a href='classes_serialisering.php?delPart=$key' id='radera'>Radera post $key </a>" . " <a href='classes_serialisering.php?updateView=$key' id='uppdatera'>Uppdatera Post </a><br>";
}
```

At first when I only had one column i tried just changing `return $row['']` to something else than 'Kund', then i also got the `foreach` error. So i figured there is something wrong with how i am trying to return the columns, but i cant seem to make it work.

I am a beginner in php so keep that in mind.

Thanks.

EDIT*****

```
interface RegisterCustomer {
function addCustomer($customername, $customertfn, $customerepost, $tirebrand, $status);
function getCustomerList();
}

class Company implements RegisterCustomer { 
protected $companyname = '';
public $CustomerList = array();

function read_data(){
    //
    //Anslut mot databas
    $conn = mysqli_connect('xxxxx', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx')
    or die('Could not establish connection to MySQL.');
    $db_connected = mysqli_select_db($conn, "xxxxxxx");

    //
    //
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Kundregistert ORDER BY ID DESC;";
    //
    //
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    //
    // Avsluta anslutning till db
    return $row['Namn'];
    mysqli_close($conn);
 }
```

---

```
    function __construct($companyname){
    $this->foretag = $companyname;
    $this->CustomerList = unserialize($this->read_data());
 }
```

I feel im lost in the code

Comment: You can only return one value from a function, although that value could be an array like $row, or even the resultset

Comment: And closing the connection after the return is meaningless, it will never be executed because return terminates execution of the function

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your php method **getCustomerList** should be modified like below;

```
public function getCustomerList()
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Kundregistert ORDER BY ID DESC;";
    //
   //
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

    $allRows = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $allRows[] = $row;
    }
    //
    // Avsluta anslutning till db
    // Return statement should be like below after mysqli_close
    //return ($row['Namn'], $row['Telefonnummer'], $row['Epost'], $row['Dacktyp'], $row['Lagerstatus'], $row['Datum']);
    mysqli_close($conn);

    return $allRows;
}
```

as you can see above, mysqli query result should be iterated and collected in an array for your situaion.

Thank you can easly foreach in your result like below;

```
foreach($company->getCustomerList() as $key => $obj){
    echo "<h3 id='id'>$key</h3> " . $obj->getcustomername() . ", " . $obj->getcustomertfn() . ", " . $obj->getcustomerepost() . "<br>" . $obj->gettirebrand() . ", " . $obj->getstatus() . ": " . $obj->getdate() . "<br>"." Radera post $key " . " Uppdatera Post";}
```

Please mind that $key will be always the index of current iteration of array. And also mind that $obj will not be a class that will have a member like getcustomerepost() etc. For that kind of using you should return an object form your method with your data.

Comment: check my edit for the full code, the code that reads the data actually is called read_data, is i should modify that then?

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try this code

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      // Add data from database to variable $array
      $array[]['Namn'] = $row['Namn'];
      $array[]['Telefonnummer'] = $row['Telefonnummer'];
      $array[]['Epost'] = $row['Epost'];
      $array[]['Dacktyp'] = $row['Dacktyp'];
      $array[]['Lagerstatus'] = $row['Lagerstatus'];
      $array[]['Datum'] = $row['Datum'];
}

// Load with this code
for($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++) {
    echo $array[$i]['Namn']."<br>";
    echo $array[$i]['Telefonnummer']."<br>";
    echo $array[$i]['Epost']."<br>";
    echo $array[$i]['Dacktyp']."<br>";
    echo $array[$i]['Lagerstatus']."<br>";
    echo $array[$i]['Datum']."<br>";
}
```